Which one is @angular-devkit/build-angular:application equivalent in @angular-builders/custom-webpack
We have requirement to hide environment variables which are comes together in build files in angular application.
We found solution using @angular-builders/custom-webpack and dotenv libraries when gone through google search.
Below is project info,
**Angular version - 17.3.0
SSR - Enabled**
We use builder application from @angular-devkit/build-angular as it provides CSR and SSR features.
There is no equivalent builder available in @angular-builders/custom-webpack for @angular-devkit/build-angular:application
Do we have any other libraries same like above or how to achieve same using @angular-builders/custom-webpack?
Below is agular.json we are using,
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-web-application": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "standalone": false
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": {
              "base":  "dist/my-web-application",
              "browser": "."
            },
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": false,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            },
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "node_modules/"
              ]
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "index": {
                "input": "src/index.prod.html",
                "output": "index.html"
              },
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "6mb",
                  "maximumError": "7mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "19kb",
                  "maximumError": "20kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            },
            "noSsr": {
              "ssr": false,
              "prerender": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "my-web-application:build:production,noSsr"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "my-web-application:build:development,noSsr"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "my-web-application:build"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


You're looking for @angular-builders/custom-esbuild.
